# Pronunciation of ий, ій, і

Tags: non-native-speaker, фонетика

As a native English speaker the endings -ий, -ій, and -і all seem to sound the same to me. I can somewhat understand the difference between -ий and -ій, but it seems almost indistinguishable. Analogous pronunciations in English would be helpful.

My first question is whether there is a noticeable pronunciation difference between these endings.

My second question is whether I could still be understood pronouncing all of them the same.

Answer (score 5):

As for English speaker [IPA for English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_Ukrainian) might be helpful:

і: `[i]`    *к**і**т, k**ey***

и: `[ɪ]`    *м**и**ша,  s**i**x*

й (at the end of the word and before consonants): `[i̯]`  *га**й**, на**й**шов, **й**ти:    co**i**n*

I'm not sure about last one: at least I pronounce "i" in *coin* totally differently.

You can just try to pronounce "й" at the end of word a little bit longer and more vowel-like comparing to "й" before vowel:

й (before vowels): `[j]`    ***й***ога **y**es

As for being understood: I've found 40454 words that have all three endings. It is usual for adjective to have all of those in different grammatical forms. For example: adjective *"високий"* (high/tall):

*високий*: single masculine grammatical gender

*високі*: plural adjective for high

*високій*: single locative case feminine grammatical gender

So it WILL be misleading, though from context it is probably possible to guess what you mean... There are other cases where words or their forms differ by these endings so it would be better to learn to distinguish them and pronounce them properly.

Comment: «Й» is always /j/, there's nothing like /i̯/ in Standard Ukrainian, there are no Ukrainian non-syllabic vowels. What's the source of that heresy? Can you give a link?

Comment: :) Of course I can. "Орфоепічний словник Погрібного" to begin with. IPA for Ukrainian link in this answer. Ukrainian wiki on phonetics: https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0
And many others. Ukrainian language has two non-syllabic vowels: ĭ and ў

Comment: З вікі, бо там багато всього й складно знайти: "Фонема /j/ твориться як приголосний [j] у позиції перед голосними. У позиції перед приголосними та в кінці слова вона набуває більшої звучності й твориться як нескладотворчий голосний [i̯]."

Comment: And in my book «Українська літературна вимова і наголос» by Жовтобрюх there's nothing about those non-syllabic vowels.

Comment: "Орфоепічний словник Погрібного" was printed in "Радянська школа" printing house, all of us know how lousy the Soviet school was. "Українська літературна вимова і наголос" was printed by "Наукова думка", the printing house of the Ukrainian Academy of Sciences.

Comment: @YellowSky I think it would be a nice high quality separate question. I haven't yet seen a book on Ukrainian pronounciation that doesn't mention these sounds. I think I can find at least two sources of 20xx that mentions these sounds. Please don't just throw out of the window new information. Those sounds are well known, for example in "вовк" second "в" is pronounced not like first one. Please don't just say that Погрібний is bad because it was printed in "Радянська школа". You can listen to his pronounciation here: https://toloka.to/t32107 Can I listen to Жовтобрюх pronounciation somewhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53447/discussion-between-kyrylo-yatsenko-and-yellow-sky).

Comment: Current results of discussion: there is no /i̯/ in Ukrainian - slashes denote allophones. I was talking about sounds, not allophones, so I've changed slashes to "[]". thank you, @YellowSky

Answer (score 4):

The main difference between the endings `-ий` and `-ій` is not the vowel, but the quality of the consonant before those endings.

Before `-ий` the consonant is not palatalized:

> великий `[vɛ'lɪkɪj]`, малий `[ma'lɪj]`, чорний `['tʂ͡ɔrnɪj]`

Before `-ій` the consonant is palatalized, it is always `[nʲ]`:

> синій `['sɪnʲij]`, майбутній `[maj'butʲnʲij]`

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `и` and `і` is like the difference between `fit` and `feet`.

I cannot think of an example of an Enlgish word with `-ий` or `-ій`. The `й` part may be hard to hear sometimes, but it is present like [ɪ] (a very short English sound i) at the end of `stay`. IPA does not show that sound like Ukrainian [j], but you will sound close enough.

If you don't pronounce `й` correctly, you will still be understood, no doubt. Human ear can take much more abuse than that.

The exact meaning can differ, if you say `и` and `і` incorrectly, but in a context it will be clear. For example, pronouncing `голодний` as `голодні` can change the meaning from `[I am] hungry` to `[you-plural are] hungry` (or `[he is] hungry` to `[they are] hungry`). So you may end up with the wrong people fed, but I guess there will be enough clues in the context to understand the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

**і**

- If sound is not alone in syllabe like in *піт*, *вирій* then it is [i] like in English [key](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/key) [kiː], [keep](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/keep) [kiːp] but shorter.
- If alone in syllabe, and next sound is not **н** or **р** like *Іван*, *імовірно*, *іти* then it *can be* a [semivowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semivowel) **і** aka [i̯]. It is shorter than common **і**. That why mentioned words can be writed also as *Йван*, *ймовірно*, *йти*.
- Same but next sound is **н** or **р** like *інший*, *ірод* then it is **и**. That why mentioned words can be rarely writed also as [*инший*](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/21407-ynshyj.html), [*ирод*](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/21420-yrod.html).

**й**

- If vowel after **й**, and they are in the same syllabe like in *йод*, *Йосип* then it is [j] like in English *yield* [jiːld], *yo-yo* [joʊ.joʊ]. For example *найочевидніша* is out this rule because **й** and **о** are not in the same syllabe.
- In other cases it is a just [i̯].

**и**

- If stressed then it is like English [six](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/six) [sɪks].
- If not then it can be sound close to unsressed **e**. Yeah, *мене* and *мине* are very similar even for Ukrainian, and it is popular mistake when someone write write **е** instead **и** or back way.

So in result do we have **ий** as [ɪi̯] *(бий)* or [ɪj] *(прийом)*? Yes.

And **ій** as [ii̯] *(бій)* or [ij] *(ійон)*? Well, yes, but actually not always.

In some cases **i** it is just **„soft” и** aka **ьи** which it is [ʲɪ]. It is not so hard to find out because you need just compare with **„hard” и** for this. It is always for all adjective: *синій* ['sɪnʲɪi̯] which is from *синь + ий*, and we have „hard” in *червоний*  [t͡ʃer'ʋɔnɪi̯] which is *червон + ий*. That is why **ій** and **ий** can sound simillar for author of question.

*Source. Олекса Синявський. Норми української мови, [ортоепія](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/ortoepia).*